# Slidetoggle jquery opening all and not hiding the other li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m using this to show a sublist:

```
    function slidecontent() {
        $('ul.joinus_subtext').slideToggle();
    }
```

and I have this markup:

```
    <ul class="joinus">
        <li onclick="slidecontent();">Benefactor
            <ul class="joinus_subtext">
                 <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia mi a turpis tempor blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
                                luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam sit amet ante sed tellus rutrum porta ut non ipsum.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li onclick="slidecontent();">Protector
            <ul class="joinus_subtext">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia mi a turpis tempor blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
                                luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam sit amet ante sed tellus rutrum porta ut non ipsum.</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The problem I have is that when I click on one **LI it toggles all, not just this one**,

What I want to achieve is that if **I click on one, it shows its content and if I click on the other, then it hides the one that was open and open the one I clicked.** Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you are using `$('ul.joinus_subtext')` will give you all the `ul` with class `joinus_subtext` and function `slideToggle` will be applied to all of them, Pass the parent object of element you want to slide to the javascript function and pass it to `selector` as a `context`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/VM4Ht/)**

*Html*

```
<li onclick="slidecontent(this);">Benefactor
```

*Javascript*

```
function slidecontent(sourceObj) {
    $('ul.joinus_subtext', sourceObj).slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: this works on closing when clicked, but when I click the other it doesn't close the one that was opened before... so it's actually doing the same problem I have now

Answer (score 0):

Use a class on the `<li>`

```
<li class="liclass">
```

Add a listener to it:

```
$('.liclass').on('click',function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="joinus">
    <li>Benefactor
        <ul class="joinus_subtext">
             <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia mi a turpis tempor blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam sit amet ante sed tellus rutrum porta ut non ipsum.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Protector
        <ul class="joinus_subtext">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacinia mi a turpis tempor blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam sit amet ante sed tellus rutrum porta ut non ipsum.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Remove the onclick from your `li element` and then add the followign jQuery

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '.joinus_subtext' ).click( function () {
        $( this ).slideToggle()
    });
});
```